# How to calculate Fridays count between two dates using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want total count of particular day between two dates  For example: If i have avariable start date and end date then need to return total count of fridays between these dates.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: There are four Fridays between the dates.

Answer (score 2):

This might help. It's pretty straight forward.

```js
let startDate = new Date('2020-03-08T12:12:06.411Z')
let endDate = new Date('2020-03-22T12:12:06.411Z')
const givenDay = 5 // 0 for sunday, 1 for monday and so on

let numberOfDates = 0

function getDays() {
    while (startDate < endDate) {
        if (startDate.getDay() === givenDay) {
          numberOfDates++
        }
        startDate.setDate( startDate.getDate() + 1 )
    }

    return numberOfDates
}

console.log(getDays())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
// days is an array of weekdays: 0 is Sunday, ..., 6 is Saturday
const countCertainDays( days, d0, d1 ) {
  var ndays = 1 + Math.round((d1-d0)/(24*3600*1000));
  var sum = function(a,b) {
    return a + Math.floor( (ndays+(d0.getDay()+6-b) % 7 ) / 7 ); };
  return days.reduce(sum,0);
}
```

example:

```
countCertainDays([5],new Date(2020,0,1),new Date(2020,2,1))
```

And another [example](https://jsbin.com/kebasesezu/edit?html,output).

Answer (score 0):

Use Moment.js when you're working with dates.

```
var start = moment('2020-01-01'), //start date
    end   = moment('2020-03-08'), //end date
    day   = 5;

var result = [];
var current = start.clone();

while (current.day(7 + day).isBefore(end)) {
  result.push(current.clone());
}

console.log(result.map(m => m.format('LLLL'))); //result
```

Read More: https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
var start_date = new Date("March 07, 2020 23:15:00");
var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

var end_date = new Date("March 07, 2021 23:15:00");    
var next_fri = new Date();
var add_days = 0;
if(start_date.getDay() == 5){
    add_days = 0;
}else if(start_date.getDay() < 5){
    add_days = 5 - start_date.getDay();
}else{
    add_days = start_date.getDay();
}
//set the next friday date from the given start date
next_fri.setDate(start_date.getDate() +  add_days);


var time_gap = (end_date.getTime() - next_fri.getTime());
var time_per_day = 1000 * 24 * 60  * 60;

var days_gap =  Math.floor(time_gap/time_per_day);
var no_fri = Math.floor(days_gap/7);
no_fri = no_fri + 1;


(no_fri is your answer, here i have assumed that end_date is always greater than start_date but if not so you would have to apply the check to inetrchange them)
```